# Git exclude certain commits and the code change and keep the other commits on top

Tags: git

I have a development branch which serves as a parent (base) for all feature branches. And the commit log looks like below:

```
ticket9: did something
ticket8: fixed something

ticket7: some action (squashed and rebased commits)
ticket7: some action (squashed and rebased commits)
ticket7: some action (squashed and rebased commits)

ticket6: implemented something
```

Is there a way where I can take out the commits and the resulting code of ticket7 from the development branch and link ticket 6 and ticket 8 like below?

```
ticket9: did something
ticket8: fixed something
ticket6: implemented something
```

Comment: Have you looked into an interactive rebase? You can drop commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, consider doing a:

- [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) of those "ticket7" commits in a new branch (starting from commit ticket6)
  See "[How to cherry pick a range of commits and merge into another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309)".
- [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase--i), which will allow you drop those same commit from your current branch

That will involve you force pushing (`git push --force`) the rewritten branch though, meaning you need to warn your colleagues working on that same branch.

Comment: Thank you, so I've read the cherry pick method and there isn't a true way of merging ticket 6 and ticket 8,9 together as the base of where ticket 8 was developed is different.